# python functions work sometimes and fail to work other times

Tags: python, eclipse

I wrote the piece of code below a while back, and had this issue then as well. I ignored it at the time and when I came back to it after asking an 'expert' to look at it, it was working fine.

The issue is, sometimes the program seems unable to run the main() on my laptop, possibly due to how heavy the algorithm is. Is there a way around this? I would hate to keep having this problem in the future. The same code is working perfectly on another computer which i have limited access to.

(P.S. laptop having the issue is a MacBook Air 2015 and it should have no problem running the program. Also, it stops after printing "hi")

It does not give and error message, it just doesn't print anything from main(). It's supposed to print a series of strings which progressively converge to "methinks it is like a weasel". In eclipse, it shows that the code is still being processed but it does not output anything that it is supposed to

```
import random

def generateOne(strlen):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
    res = ""
    for i in range(strlen):
        res = res + alphabet[random.randrange(27)]
    return res

def score(goal, teststring):
    numSame = 0
    for i in range(len(goal)):
        if goal[i] == teststring[i]:
            numSame = numSame + 1
    return numSame / len(goal)

def main():
    goalstring = "methinks it is like a weasel"
    chgoal = [0]*len(goalstring)
    newstring = generateOne(28)
    workingstring = list(newstring)
    countvar = 0
    finalstring = ""
    while score(list(goalstring), workingstring) < 1:
        if score(goalstring, newstring) > 0:
            for j in range(len(goalstring)):
                if goalstring[j] == newstring[j] and chgoal[j] == 0:
                    workingstring[j] = newstring[j]
                    chgoal[j] = 1
                    finalstring = "".join(workingstring)
                    countvar = countvar + 1
                    print(finalstring)
        newstring = generateOne(28)
    finalstring = "".join(workingstring)
    print(finalstring) 
    print(countvar)

print("hi")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
print("ho")
```

Comment: what's the error message? you will have to give a little more information

Comment: No error message, it just doesn't print anything from main(). It's supposed to print a series of strings which progressively converge to "methinks it is like a weasel". In eclipse, it shows that the code is still being processed but it does not output anything that it is supposed to

Comment: unrelated: `res = res + alphabet[random.randrange(27)]` == `res += random.choice(alphabet)` or:  `def generateOne(strlen):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
    return ''.join(random.choices(alphabet,k=strlen))
`

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize a bit. Strings are immutable - every time you append one char to a string a new string is created and replaces the old one. Use lists of chars instead - also do not use `"".join()` all the time for printing purposes if you can print the list of chars by decomposing and a seperator of "":

```
import random

def generateOne(strlen):
    """Create one in one random-call, return as list, do not iterativly add to string"""
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
    return random.choices(alphabet,k=strlen)

def score(goal, teststring):
    """Use zip and generator expr. for summing/scoring"""
    return sum(1 if a==b else 0 for a,b in zip(goal,teststring))/len(goal)

def main():
    goalstring = list("methinks it is like a weasel") # use a list
    newstring = generateOne(28) # also returns a list
    workingstring = newstring [:] # copy
    countvar = 0
    while score(goalstring, workingstring) < 1:
        if score(goalstring, newstring) > 0:
            for pos,c in enumerate(goalstring): # enumerate for getting the index
                # test if equal, only change if not yet ok
                if c == newstring[pos] and workingstring[pos] != c: 
                    workingstring[pos] = newstring[pos] # could use c instead
                    countvar += 1
                    print(*workingstring, sep="") # print decomposed with sep of ""  
                                                  # instead of "".join()
        newstring = generateOne(28)

    finalstring = "".join(workingstring) # create result once ... 
                                         # although its same as goalstring
                                         # so we could just assing that one
    print(finalstring) 
    print(countvar)

print("hi")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = datetime.datetime.now()
    main()
    print(datetime.datetime.now()-s)
print("ho")
```

Timings with printouts are very unrelieable. If I comment the `print` printing the intermediate steps to the final solution and use a `random.seed(42)' - I get for mine:

```
0:00:00.012536
0:00:00.012664
0:00:00.008590
0:00:00.012575
0:00:00.012576
```

and for yours:

```
0:00:00.017490
0:00:00.017427
0:00:00.013481
0:00:00.017657
0:00:00.013210
```

I am quite sure this wont solve your laptops issues, but still - it is a bit faster.